# Host A sends 5 segments back to back to host B (TCP)

Tags: tcp

I have run into the following question in one of the exercises I'm doing:

> Host A sends Host B 5 segments, S1 to S5, they have sequence numbers
>   20,50,62,90,100. The segments arrive to host B in the order of
>   S2,S1,S5,S4. S3 is lost. In the acknowledgments for the arrived
>   segments that host B sends to A, what will be the ack numbers?

I have no idea how to approach this question, I have only done questions like

> Suppose Host A sends two TCP segments back to back to Host B over a
>   TCP connection. The first segment has sequence number 90; the second
>   has sequence number 110.

if segment 1 is lost then host B sends back one ack of 90.

How do I do the question when the host is sending 5 segments? I have looked everywhere online but every example on this topic I have found online is the question I posted above where they send two segments of sequence numbers 90 and 110.

What if the segments arrived in the order of S4,S2,S3,S1 and S5 is lost?

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question? Today? and had an answer? and been told it's off-topic? I've seen this question before.

Comment: I have asked this but no I didn't get an answer, only you who didn't actually answer my question and called it off topic like you're doing now. How is it off topic? how is this not related to TCP? Not sure how all you got from my last post was "haha he obviously wants the answer to this exercise" when I specifically said I was looking for explanation on how they got the answer. I literally spent 80% of the post explaining just that, but I guess reading is hard. All you posted was the answer I already had and called it off topic for no reason, this is completely related to TCP and CS.

Comment: Please do enlighten me on how a thread I created about TCP in the TCP category is off topic? are people only allowed to talk about a select few aspects of TCP here? I literally cannot find even one example of my topic online, where do you suggest I find the information? Also its not even the same question, its just the same type of question but a different exercise I would better understand if someone explained. There's a reason I deleted that one.